# Different words for clothing

Tags: hebrew, clothing, language

Whats the difference between kasah (covering) and labash (covering)? And when we look to clothes then what's the difference between kesut and lebush? And what about beged (cloths) ? Please show me some examples from the Torah, and define them for me.

Comment: J.Levi welcome to Mi.Yodeya - Hope you stick around and continue to contribute with your questions and answers.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35583

Answer (score 3):

Malbim has an entry in his ["*Ya'ir Or*"](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52213&st=&pgnum=25) about different words for clothing. I will summarize his opinion regarding the words you are asking about.

- **בגד**: This is a general term that refers to all types of clothing. (E.g. [Exod. 29:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0229.htm), [Judg. 14:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0714.htm))
- **כסות**: A garment that is not intended to be worn in the normal way, but rather to just cover up with. (E.g. [Job 31:19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t2731.htm))
- **לבוש**: A garment that is not intended for everyday, every-person wear, but rather for special occasions or special people. (E.g. [Esther 4:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t3304.htm), [6:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t3306.htm); [Prov. 31:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t2831.htm))

Now for the verb forms, it's kind of the same idea:

- **לבש**: To wear something in the conventional sense. (E.g. [I Sam. 28:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t08a28.htm), [Num. 20:28](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0420.htm))
- **כסה**: To use something as a covering without necessarily wearing it normally. (Or, it seems, even when wearing normally, if the primary reason is to cover up one's nudity.) (E.g. [I Sam 19:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t08a19.htm), [Ezek. 18:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t1218.htm))

Comment: Not to hold you accountable for the Malbim, but aren't the Kohen's (special people and occassion) clothing called בגד?

Answer (score 2):

[Chosem Tachanus page 166](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38635&st=&pgnum=216&hilite=) (by [Abraham Bedersi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Bedersi)) explains the following differences. The word Levush is the standard word for clothing. Beged is something which is not worn - for example U'beged Klayim Shaatnez. Kesus is used for something that covers over. Simla is something you lay upon. Meil is a valuable type of clothing which prestigious people wear.

Comment: What about the regular term for Tallith Katan = Beged?

Comment: Shaatnez is for things you don't wear?

Comment: Shouldn't it be Chosem Tochnis? ([Ezekiel 28:12](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1228.htm#12))