# בגד (Begged) and מלבוש (Malbush)

Tags: words, tanach, clothing

Sometimes the Torah uses the word בגד for clothing, for example [Vayikra 11:32](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0311.htm#32), and sometimes it uses מלבוש, for example [Iyov 27:16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2727.htm#16), or לבוש, as in [Ester 6:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3306.htm#8).  [This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26880/4794) discusses the difference between the two.

The verb is always constructed from the latter (לבוש), even when the noun is the former (בגד), for example [Vayikra 16:23](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0316.htm#23) - וּבָא אַהֲרֹן אֶל-אֹהֶל מוֹעֵד וּפָשַׁט אֶת-בִּגְדֵי הַבָּד אֲשֶׁר לָבַשׁ בְּבֹאוֹ אֶל-הַקֹּדֶשׁ..

Why is the word for normal wearing constructed from the word for non-normal clothing?  And why does the word בגד not have a verb form which refers to clothing?

Comment: [Yeshayahu 24:16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1024.htm#16)

Comment: See more Malbim here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32825&st=&pgnum=129 The Malbim does connect the noun בגד with the verb בוגד to betray. Just as clothing covers up, so too a person who betrays covers up his treachery by appearing to be a friend. (Beyond פשט, on a deeper level, there's a בגד/בוגד connection in regards to the sin of Adam.)

Comment: @Ephraim That's a nice drush, but there is no verb of בגד in the context of wearing.  We never find getting dressed using בוגד or מבגד or any construct.

Comment: First, is this a dupe of [http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26835/](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26835/different-words-for-clothing?noredirect=1&lq=1)? Second, is this even the right forum for this? Granted that the word appears in Tanach, is this really a question that relates to Judaism so much as relates to Hebrew language?